# PDO general error: 2006 mysql server has gone away

Tags: php, pdo

I am using linux and tried to create some tables using php 7.2 but it will give an error as follows, when I execute command. Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
>   [ErrorException] PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away

```
class Database extends PDO{
    function __construct(){
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        try{
            parent::__construct(DB_TYPE.':host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset=utf8',DB_USER,DB_PASS, $options);
        }catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Got PDOException\n";
            var_dump($this);
        }

    }
}
```

I can not set the instructions for this page to the class I have
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html

Comment: The `ATTR_PERSISTENT` option causes problems. PHP thinks the connection is still there, but it somehow closed. So you get an error. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26620625/1685196)

Comment: No, unfortunately, this does not matter at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$db->exec('SET session wait_timeout=60');
```